# Visualforce - Display all records on VF page from custom object

Tags: visualforce, outputfield

So I want to display **all** 'sites' from the Site custom object on a Visualforce page called Launchpad.

```
<apex:pageBlock>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Site__c}" var="site">
          <apex:column value="{!site.Site_Name__c}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I am using for the header of the VF page:

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="hidden" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Site__c">
```

But I cannot seem to render anything. This is the API Name for the field I want to print: `Site_Name__c` and this is the object API Name: `Site__c`.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It seems that Site__c is a custom object. isn't it??then why you have used  standardController="Site__c"?

Comment: @SubhasisKar this is fine, Custom object can be applicable for standardController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `standardController` with `recordSetVar` to list of all the sites.

```
<apex:page standardController="Site__c" recordSetVar="sites">
    <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!sites}" var="site">
              <apex:column value="{!site.Site_Name__c}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

For more information, [Accessing Data with List Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_access_data.htm)

`StandardController` without `recordSetVar` will show only single record detail.

Comment: Perfect! This worked for me. Although, final question, how would I display just the records without the field name?

Comment: you can try to achieve your 2nd requirement and in case you face issues, please post that separately.