# Visualforce sites.com page - Display all records on VF page from custom object

Tags: visualforce, permissions, force.com-sites

I am trying to build a Sites website so I can make a blog of technical tips for my users available from Salesforce.

I have followed the guidance on [Visualforce - Display all records on VF page from custom object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170874/visualforce-display-all-records-on-vf-page-from-custom-object) and when I click on preview in the developer console all works well, however when I try to access the page through the website address on the Sites page, the page loads the header information but not the list of records.

```
<apex:page standardController="techtip__c" recordSetVar="ttips" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <apex:pageBlock title="TechTips">
        <apex:form>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ttips}" var="a">
                <apex:column value="{!a.Title__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Any advice? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the permissions for the site (guest user) in accessing this custom object and its fields.

Comment: As Phil says, check the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emergency_response_vm_guest_profile_config.htm&type=5) on guest user permissions.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I checked I have granted Guest User Licence Basic Read access (the option is checked) for the custom object. When I load the page as preview as a VF page - it loads OK, but when I test on Sites it shows just my fixed header and no records. @PhilW

Comment: Check sharing of the records. Guest User sharing options were recently changed.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW Tried that added access for the techtips userId.  Here is the url for the external page on my sandbox - https://techtips01-test01.aus28s.sfdc-vwfla6.force.com/. When I load the VF page it shows two entries and pictures from those entries. Still stumped. VFSecurity - allows read and the ttips profile. Sharing allows ttips profile, permissions on the object allows read. Is it because I am doing this on a sandbox?